# Finding the Posterior Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I am trying to solve this problem: A new drug has p chance of working, where p is a random variable with density $f_p(a)\sim Beta(2,3)$. They test the drug on five animals, three of whom show that the drug works. What is the posterior distribution on $p$ given this information?

I found the beta density as: $2p(1−p)2⋅\mathbb(p \in [0,1]$ But I am not sure where to begin?

Can I just add $(2,3)+(3,2)$ to get $Beta(5,5)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prior is

$$\pi(\theta)\propto \theta(1-\theta)^2$$

The likelihood is

$$p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)\propto \theta^3(1-\theta)^2$$

Multiplying you get

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\propto \theta^4(1-\theta)^4$$

Thus

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\sim  Beta(5;5)$$

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up!